# How to change default port number of KotlinJS

Tags: kotlin-js

I have a very simple kotlinJS project.

I have HTML file referencing to my hello world scripts and so on...

It runs and everything is okay.
But my question is how to change the default port number?
Can I somehow configure to be port 3000?
This is very easy on nodejs, but I did not find a nice example of how to do it with kotlinJS.

I assume it is something with gradle or some config file... But I need help here, because I was not able to find a way how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can config the port with `webpack.config.d`:

```
config.devServer = config.devServer || {}
config.devServer.port = ...
```

and in gradle:

```
kotlin {
  js {
    browser {
       runTask {
           devServer = KotlinWebpackConfig.DevServer(
               port = 3000,
               contentBase = listOf("$buildDir/processedResources/frontend/main")
           )
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.
when i start the `browserDevelopmentRun` task, it still runs on 8080

Comment: Oh, i had is configured in webpackTask instead of runTask - however, now it automatically opens the browser on port 3000 but shows 'Cannot GET /'

Comment: @IARI: Did you add index.html to src/main/resources ?

Comment: well - at some point it just worked, without me changing anything ^^

Answer (score 4):

What ended up working for me was this `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("js")
}

kotlin {
    js {
        browser {
            runTask {
                devServer = devServer?.copy(port = 3000)
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    sourceSets["main"].dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:1.4.2")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-js:0.7.2")
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this as I came up with the same solution but the 'runTask' is now 'commonWebpackConfig' in the template